# subquery based on two date coloumn having one week range data

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have two date column in a table, one for date of question posted and another for answer. For example whenever a new question is asked its date is stored in q_date column and whenever some answer that question its date is stored in a_date column.
Now I want all the question asked within one week and all the questions which are answered within one week.
Can anyone explain me a query by using join or subquery

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? Some sql query that you tried and didn't work !

Comment: Can you show some effort please?

Comment: Yes here is my query i have used. "SELECT DISTINCT (ans_id), q_ans.a_date FROM table q_ans WHERE q_ans.a_date BETWEEN date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND q_ans.type = 'A' AND q_ans.live_question =1 AND q_ans.ans_id IN ( SELECT q_ques.q_id FROM qa_posts q_ques WHERE q_ques.type = 'Q' ) order by q_ans.a_date DESC".   When I removing this "q_ans.a_date BETWEEN date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)" form query i am getting perfect result.

Comment: Yes @Vandita here is my query i have used. "SELECT DISTINCT (ans_id), q_ans.a_date FROM table q_ans WHERE q_ans.a_date BETWEEN date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND q_ans.type = 'A' AND q_ans.live_question =1 AND q_ans.ans_id IN ( SELECT q_ques.q_id FROM qa_posts q_ques WHERE q_ques.type = 'Q' ) order by q_ans.a_date DESC".   When I removing this "q_ans.a_date BETWEEN date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)" form query i am getting perfect result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Biegeleisen  Can you please explain what effort you want to see? Should I explain my question more?

Comment: So each question can only have, at most, one answer? Also, note that there is an edit button.

Comment: `BETWEEN date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND q_ans.type = 'A' ` ?????

Comment: @Strawberry I'm thinking one record per question, and it has a posting date and date for when it was answered.

Comment: Oh, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    q_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY OR
    a_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

This will return all record corresponding to questions or answers happening with the last 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
 Select * from q_ans where DATEDIFF(WEEK,q_ans.q_date,q_ans.a_date) = 1
```

This will give all records for which answer date is in one week range of question date

Comment: DATEDIFF() does not accept three parameters. It takes only two date as its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AND condition for BETWEEN clause. You can try

```
WHERE q_ans.a_date BETWEEN date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()
```